# Gmail loading error

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gmail

Whenever I load gmail on my Windows 7 machine with the latest Chrome (40.0.2214.11 m), I have been getting a "Loading error, please try Standard HTML view". This has been happening for the last week or so.

I have closed and restarted my browser multiple times, and I have even reset my machine multiple times. Still no dice.

I just cleared my cookies and cached files for the last week and still no progress.

The weird thing is that it seems like it could be a network issue, but when I try to access Gmail from my Macbook on the same network, it has no problems.

What could be causing this?

I have searched for other people having this issue and can't find anything recent. Doesn't seem Google has a Gmail 'status' site that tells you what is happening on their end.

Comment: Have you tried `ipconfig /flushdns`, followed by `ipconfig /registerdns`?

Comment: Are you using same chrome from mac to access gmail or any other browser.Since i have faced the issue due to low download speed of the browser

Comment: @Yass I just tried `/flushdns` and that hasn't worked. I tried `/registerdns` but it says that the operation needs to be elevanted.

Comment: @vembutech I am using Chrome on Mac too.

Comment: You need to run the command line as an Administrator.

Comment: @Yass Yeh...i just did that. No dice. Do I have to reset cookies again?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Do you have any other Windows 7 machines on your network?

Comment: @Yass Unfortunately not. Just other macs.

Comment: You said you reset your machine a couple of times? Do you mean a System Restore?

Comment: LOL. No...a restart. I am not doing a system restore. No way that's the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I may have figured this out. I had a Chrome & Gmail extension (Mail Tracker to be specific) that has crashed in recent times. It seems that was crashing Gmail overall.

I didn't have it installed on my Macbook, just on my Windows machine.

I disabled it, and so far so good.

We shall see if it continues to work.

**Edit 1**

It seems that was the solution. It hasn't crashed or I haven't had any issues in the hours since.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check that you're using a browser that works with Gmail

Step 2: Check your browser extensions or applications

Step 3: Clear your browser's cache & cookies

Step 4: Check your Gmail labs

Comment: Step 1: check that Google Chrome works with Google Mail?  Step 2: check browsers or applications for what, and how?  Steps 3 & 4: check for what, exactly, and how?  This is too generic and vague to be of much use.  But also notice that the OP solved the problem 3 yrs ago.